# String format procedure similar to writeln

Tags: string, file, delphi, format

With `writeln` I can format numbers into a line of text.

```
var 
  file: text;
  mystring: string;

begin
  writeln(file,'Result is: ', var1:8:2,' | ', var2:8:2,' |');
end;
```

Is there a similar easy to use procedure in Delphi that would procedure similar result

```
  _format_string(mystring, 'Result is: ', var1:8:2,' | ', var2:8:2,' |');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Exact answer is *no*, it is a feature built into language itself (that is, Sacred Standard Pascal). There is no syntax which allows us (programmers) to write such subroutines.

Comment: One of the things you have to take into account is that as of Delphi 2009, `WriteLn` and `WriteLn` use single-byte `AnsiString` whereas `Format` and such are `UnicodeString`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function:

```
mystring := Format('The image dimensions are %d × %d.', [640, 480]);
```

Answer (score 12):

Technically the answer is "yes". But it's not recommended.

You can write your own [text file device driver](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_Routines_and_Input-Output#Text_File_Device_Drivers) based on the [System.TTextRec](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TTextRec) type.

I've done this in the past (especially in the Turbo Pascal era) for debugging purposes. It is a lot of work, and requires you to write a special `MyAssign` procedure, and be sure to close the `Text` file using the `TTextRec` in a `try..finally` block. Cumbersome, but doable.

A much easier alternative is [using the Format function as described by Andreas Rejbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993967/string-format-procedure-similar-to-writeln/17994143#17994143).

The cool thing about using `Format` is that you use for [Format Strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings) not only to parameterize things like `width` and `precision` inside that `Format String`, but also as paramaters like you normally would provide values.

You can get very close to using a `width` of 8 and a `precision` of 2, like the example in your question.

For instance, to quote the documentation:

```
Format ('%*.*f', [8, 2, 123.456]);
```

> is equivalent to:

```
Format ('%8.2f', [123.456]);
```

That is a much overlooked feature of `Format` and `Format Strings`.

Comment: Sweet -- never knew that.

Comment: Nice. Still pales in comparison to some of the formatting that you can do in Python, IMV.

Comment: @David: What kind of awesome formatting can you do in Python?

Answer (score 6):

Although Jeroen doesn't recommend it, I have done something like this about a year ago - just to learn how to do it. This is the code:

```
type
  TTextFile = class
  private type
    TTextRecHelper = record helper for TTextRec
    public
      function GetTextFile: TTextFile;
      procedure SetTextFile(const Value: TTextFile);
      property TextFile: TTextFile read GetTextFile write SetTextFile;
    end;
  private var
    FBuilder: TStringBuilder;
    class function TextClose(var F: TTextRec): Integer; static;
    class function TextIgnore(var F: TTextRec): Integer; static;
    class function TextInput(var F: TTextRec): Integer; static;
    class function TextOpen(var F: TTextRec): Integer; static;
    class function TextOutput(var F: TTextRec): Integer; static;
    procedure AppendString(const Value: string);
    procedure AssignFile(var F: Text);
  public
    var F: Text;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function ToString: string; override;
  end;

constructor TTextFile.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FBuilder := TStringBuilder.Create();
  AssignFile(F);
  Rewrite(F);
end;

destructor TTextFile.Destroy;
begin
  Close(F);
  FBuilder.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TTextFile.AppendString(const Value: string);
begin
  FBuilder.Append(Value);
end;

procedure TTextFile.AssignFile(var F: Text);
begin
  FillChar(F, SizeOf(F), 0);
  with TTextRec(F)do
  begin
    Mode := fmClosed;
    BufSize := SizeOf(Buffer);
    BufPtr := @Buffer;
    OpenFunc := @TextOpen;
    TextFile := Self;
  end;
end;

class function TTextFile.TextClose(var F: TTextRec): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;

class function TTextFile.TextIgnore(var F: TTextRec): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;

class function TTextFile.TextInput(var F: TTextRec): Integer;
begin
  F.BufPos := 0;
  F.BufEnd := 0;
  Result := 0;
end;

class function TTextFile.TextOpen(var F: TTextRec): Integer;
begin
  if F.Mode = fmInput then
  begin
    F.InOutFunc := @TextInput;
    F.FlushFunc := @TextIgnore;
    F.CloseFunc := @TextIgnore;
  end else
  begin
    F.Mode := fmOutput;
    F.InOutFunc := @TextOutput;
    F.FlushFunc := @TextOutput;
    F.CloseFunc := @TextClose;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

class function TTextFile.TextOutput(var F: TTextRec): Integer;
var
  AStr: AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(AStr, F.BufPos);
  Move(F.BufPtr^, AStr[1], F.BufPos);
  F.TextFile.AppendString(string(AStr));
  F.BufPos := 0;
  Result := 0;
end;

function TTextFile.ToString: string;
begin
  Close(F);
  result := FBuilder.ToString;
  Rewrite(F);
end;

function TTextFile.TTextRecHelper.GetTextFile: TTextFile;
begin
  Move(UserData[1], Result, Sizeof(Result));
end;

procedure TTextFile.TTextRecHelper.SetTextFile(const Value: TTextFile);
begin
  Move(Value, UserData[1], Sizeof(Value));
end;
```

Example of how to use it according to your question:

```
  tf := TTextFile.Create;
  try
    Writeln(tf.F, 'Result is: ', var1:8:2,' | ', var2:8:2,' |');
    Caption := tf.ToString;
  finally
    tf.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: +1; well done. Reminds me of code I wrote in Turbo Pascal. Sans the `try...finally` though, and with `object` style classes (:

Answer (score 2):

### Note about Writeln

```
Writeln(file, 'Result is: ', var1:8:2,' | ', var2:8:2,' |');
```

*Output:*

```
Result is:     4.50 |     0.67 |
```

It seems that Delphi does old Pascal formatting without honoring [DecimalSeparator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.DecimalSeparator). This is the reason why `Writeln` output uses `.` and my other approaches below use `,` (I've a [Spanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) version of Windows).

### TStringBuilder

In modern Delphi versions, [TStringBuilder](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder) provides an elegant way for string concatenation with support for [fluent interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103877/fluent-interface-in-delphi). It has limited formatting capabilities, but includes a `Format` flavor (which, as the regular `Format` function, is very useful, but lacks type checking):

```
sb := TStringBuilder.Create;
try       
  sb.Append('Result is: ').Append(var1).Append(' | ').Append(var2).Append(' |');
  Memo.Lines.Add(sb.ToString);
  sb.Clear;
  sb.AppendFormat('Result is: %8.2f | %8.2f |', [var1, var2]);
  Memo.Lines.Add(sb.ToString);
finally                     
  sb.Free;
end;
```

*Output:*

```
Result is: 4,5 | 0,666666666666667 |
Result is:     4,50 |     0,67 |
```

### Insertion operator

Using some tricks such as operator overloading and [closures](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi), it is possible to mimic the **C++** [ostream insertion operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/):

---

```
Memo.Lines.Add(stringout < 'My ' < 5 < ' cents' < soEndl < '2/3: ' < soPrec(4) < 2/3);
```

*Output:*

```
My 5 cents  
2/3: 0,6667
```

---

Your example:

```
Memo.Lines.Add(
  stringout
    < 'Result is: ' < soWidth(8) < soPrec(2) < var1 < ' | '
    < soWidth(8) < soPrec(2) < var2 < ' |'
);
```

*Output:*

```
Result is:     4,50 |     0,67 |
```

---

When Delphi supports operator overloading in classes, implementation would be much cleaner. Meanwhile, using records for operator overloading and interfaces for automatic memory management do the trick:

```
type
  PStringOut = ^TStringOut;

  TStringOutManipulatorRef = reference to procedure(pso: PStringOut);

  PStringOutInternalStorage = ^TStringOutInternalStorage;

  TStringOutInternalStorage = record
    Data: TStringBuilder;
    Width, Precision: integer;
    procedure ClearFormat; inline;
    function GetFormatString(formatType: char): string;
  end;

  IStringOutInternal = interface
    function TheStorage: PStringOutInternalStorage;
  end;

  TStringOutInternal = class(TInterfacedObject, IStringOutInternal)
  strict private
    Storage: TStringOutInternalStorage;
  private
    constructor Create;
    function TheStorage: PStringOutInternalStorage;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TStringOut = record
  private
    Buffer: IStringOutInternal;
  public
    // insertion operator
    class operator LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: string): TStringOut;
    class operator LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: char): TStringOut;
    class operator LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: integer): TStringOut;
    class operator LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: double): TStringOut;
    class operator LessThan(const this: TStringOut; manipulator: TStringOutManipulatorRef): TStringOut; inline;

    // implicit conversion to string ("extraction" operator)
    class operator Implicit(const this: TStringOut): string; inline;
  end;

{ TStringOutInternalStorage }

procedure TStringOutInternalStorage.ClearFormat;
begin
  Width := 0;
  Precision := 0;
end;

function TStringOutInternalStorage.GetFormatString(formatType: char): string;
begin
  Result := '%';
  if Width > 0 then
    Result := Result + IntToStr(Width);
  if Precision > 0 then
    Result := Result + '.' + IntToStr(Precision);
  Result := Result + formatType;
end;

{ TStringOutInternal }

constructor TStringOutInternal.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  Storage.Data := TStringBuilder.Create;
end;

destructor TStringOutInternal.Destroy;
begin
  Storage.Data.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TStringOutInternal.TheStorage: PStringOutInternalStorage;
begin
  Result := @Storage;
end;

{ TStringOut }

class operator TStringOut.Implicit(const this: TStringOut): string;
begin
  Result := this.Buffer.TheStorage.Data.ToString;
end;

class operator TStringOut.LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: string): TStringOut;
begin
  this.Buffer.TheStorage.Data.AppendFormat(this.Buffer.TheStorage.GetFormatString('s'), [add]);
  this.Buffer.TheStorage.ClearFormat;
  Result.Buffer := this.Buffer;
end;

class operator TStringOut.LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: char): TStringOut;
begin
  this.Buffer.TheStorage.Data.Append(add);
  this.Buffer.TheStorage.ClearFormat;
  Result.Buffer := this.Buffer;
end;

class operator TStringOut.LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: integer): TStringOut;
begin
  this.Buffer.TheStorage.Data.AppendFormat(this.Buffer.TheStorage.GetFormatString('d'), [add]);
  this.Buffer.TheStorage.ClearFormat;
  Result.Buffer := this.Buffer;
end;

class operator TStringOut.LessThan(const this: TStringOut; add: double): TStringOut;
var
  s: PStringOutInternalStorage;
begin
  s := this.Buffer.TheStorage;

  if s.Precision <> 0
  then s.Data.AppendFormat(s.GetFormatString('f'), [add])
  else s.Data.AppendFormat(s.GetFormatString('g'), [add]);

  s.ClearFormat;
  Result.Buffer := this.Buffer;
end;

class operator TStringOut.LessThan(const this: TStringOut; manipulator: TStringOutManipulatorRef): TStringOut;
begin
  Result := this;
  manipulator(@Result);
end;

{ Manipulators }

function soEndl: TStringOutManipulatorRef;
begin
  Result :=
    procedure(pso: PStringOut)
    begin
      pso.Buffer.TheStorage.Data.AppendLine;
      pso.Buffer.TheStorage.ClearFormat;
    end;
end;

function soWidth(value: integer): TStringOutManipulatorRef;
begin
  Result :=
    procedure(pso: PStringOut)
    begin
      pso.Buffer.TheStorage.Width := value;
    end;
end;

function soPrec(value: integer): TStringOutManipulatorRef;
begin
  Result :=
    procedure(pso: PStringOut)
    begin
      pso.Buffer.TheStorage.Precision := value;
    end;
end;

{ The stringout "constructor" }

function stringout: TStringOut; inline;
begin
  Result.Buffer := TStringOutInternal.Create;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for the `DecimalSeparator` observation, and for the C++ `ostream` simulation.