# Why does concatenating string functions put the results in the wrong order?

Tags: delphi, lazy-evaluation, string-concatenation

i'm using something like that to define a SQL insert command:

```
sql := 'insert into table(a, b, c) values (' + formatfunction(a) + ', ' + 
                                               formatfunction(b) + ', ' +
                                               formatfunction(c) + ');';
```

after the assignment, the variable sql contains the formatted values ​​of a, b, c in a different order, resulting in something like this:

```
insert into (a, b, c) values ​​('value in c', 'value in a', 'value in b');
```

may be some problem with the compiler optimization?

sorry about the poor sample code, full executable code below:

```
procedure Execute(var v : String);
  function ExtractValue(var Content: String; Separator: Char = '|'): String;
  var
    vpHead,
    vpTail,
    vpContent: PChar;
    vsValor: String;
  begin
    vpContent := PChar(Content);
    Result := '';
    if (vpContent = nil) or
       (vpContent^=#0) then
      Exit;
    vpTail := vpContent;
    vpHead := vpTail;

    while not (CharInSet(vpTail^, [Separator]) or (vpTail^=#0)) do
      vpTail := StrNextChar(vpTail);

    if (vpHead^ <> #0) then
    begin
      if (vpHead <> vpTail) then
      begin
        SetString(vsValor, vpHead, vpTail - vpHead);
        Result := vsValor;
      end
      else
        Result := '';
    end;

    Content := Copy(Content, Length(vsValor) + 2, (Length(Content) - Length(vsValor)) + 1);
  end;

  function FormatAsDate(const s: String): TDate;
  begin
    Result := 0;

    if Trim(s) <> '' then
      Result := StrToDateDef(Copy(s, 1, 2) + '/' + Copy(s, 3, 2) + '/' + Copy(s, 5, 4), 0);
  end;

  function AsCurrency(const s: string): Double;
  begin
    Result := StrToFloatDef(s, 0);
  end;

  function AsDate(const s: string): string;
  var
    d: TDate;
  begin
    d := FormatAsDate(s);

    if d = 0 then
      Result := QuotedStr('null')
    else
      Result := QuotedStr(FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', d));
  end;

  function AsText(const s: string): string;
  begin
    Result := QuotedStr(s);
  end;
begin
  v :=
    'INSERT INTO TABLE (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M) VALUES (' +
     AsText(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     AsText(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     AsText(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     AsText(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     AsText(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     AsText(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     AsDate(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     AsDate(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     StringReplace(FloatToStr(AsCurrency(ExtractValue(v))), ',', '.', []) + ', ' +
     StringReplace(FloatToStr(AsCurrency(ExtractValue(v))), ',', '.', []) + ', ' +
     AsText(ExtractValue(v)) + ', ' +
     StringReplace(FloatToStr(AsCurrency(ExtractValue(v))), ',', '.', []) + ', ' +
     StringReplace(FloatToStr(AsCurrency(ExtractValue(v))), ',', '.', []) + ');';
end;
```

using the input string '04368898000106|06|00|||3413572|26102011|31102011|1656,81|334,57||0,00|0,00', the values ​​of the insert command are in a different order than presented in the input string.

Comment: @tetri: Mason is right. You have some bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I'm sure like a lot of offices around the world we use this exact string concatenation in our SQL queries and have never experienced a similar issue. My experience is limited to 2010 and XE2 but looking at your sample code I can't see a reason why you would get this behavior. More detailed code would be helpful.

Comment: if this line of code that you posted is exactly the same line from your code, set a breakpoint and interrogate the values before they are sent to through the format function... I agree with the rest of the comments, chances are your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're missing the single-quote escape, i.e. sql := 'insert into table(a, b, c) values ( '' ' + formatfunction(a) + ' '', '' ' + formatfunction(b) + ' '', '' ' + formatfunction(c) + ''' );'; copy paste this code and see if it works.

Comment: @Dorin If the real code was written with `=` instead of `:=`, then it would be a compile error.

Comment: Also, you should never ever build a SQL query that way.  Concatenation leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks, a serious security hole that someone could use to hack into your system.  Please don't write another line of SQL-generating code until you've read up on SQL injection and how to prevent it. (Not exaggerating. I mean it.  Stop right now, before you cause a security breach.)

Comment: +1 The update to the question is good and now it all makes sense.

Comment: What a coincidence that this comes up so soon after this closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010456/in-delphi-are-parameters-evaluated-in-order-when-passed-into-a-method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code depends on the evaluation order of operands in an expression. That evaluation order is not defined.

Looking at a simpler case, consider this code:

```
x := f1(a) + f2(b);
```

There is no guarantee over which order the function calls `f1()` and `f2()` will be executed. You, presumably, expect `f1()` to execute before `f2()` but the compiler does not guarantee that and in practice I believe that these operands will usually be evaluated right to left.

In your code, the operands in your expression involve a function call, `ExtractValue()`, that has a side effect which modifies its argument. Since the operands in your expression are not evaluated left to right, the calls to `ExtractValue()` do not occur in the same order as they appear in the expression. And since `ExtractValue()` has a side-effect which influences the rest of the expression, the results are dependent on the evaluation order.

You will need to re-work this code so that the calls to `ExtractValue()` occur in separate statements.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The issue is that the calls to `ExtractValue()` do not occur in the same order in which they are written in the expression, as I tried to explain above.

Comment: there is no compiler directive to ensure the execution order?

Comment: No there is not. Split the expression into multiple statements, perhaps using a string builder.